# smpboot do_boot_cpu failed CentOS7

Tags: centos, cisco

Проблема в том что после перезагрузки сервера CISCO с настроенным рэйд массивом, перестала загружаться система, ошибка smpboot: do_boot cpu failed(-1) to wakeup CPU#1 и так до CPU#24 затем сам делает ребут и все по новой, как фиксить данную проблему? если система не загружается ?

Comment: Где-то читал, что такая беда возникает после установки последней версии ядра, и лечится откатом на предыдущую версию.

Comment: @socode да такая беда произошла после обновления, напишите подробно как лечится, т.е как откатить и т.д. Оформите как ответ и я закрою тему (жаль что не известно почему так происходит). Спасибо

Comment: Сразу скажу, я ни разу не админ, но постараюсь вам помочь чем смогу. :) А какая версия ядра у вас сейчас установлена?

Comment: @socode Версия ядра - 4.1.12-94.3.9.el7uek.x86_64

Comment: @socode Поторопитесь пожалуйста, конкурс завершен и осталось 20 часов для присуждения победителя, не хотелось бы что бы баллы были потеряны, и награда не досталась вам по праву.

Comment: Простите, но я думаю я не смогу вам помочь. Знаний нахватает. Всё что я могу вам подсказать это направление. В данном случае откат версии ядра. Но я думаю вы и сами это поняли. Попробуйте написать в поддержку CISCO, возможно они вам помогут. Удачи вам! ;)

Comment: @socode Теперь тоже самое оформите в ответ. И закрываем тему. Спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets, по поводу вашей правки ответа: автор 2 раза явно написал CISCO: в комментарии к вопросу, и в ответе, а два раза ошибиться проблематично. Поэтому второй раз уже отклоняю правку. Если вы несогласны с автором ответа, напишите это в комментарии к ответу, а не правьте ответ.

Comment: Ув @insolor я написал что данная проблема произошла на сервере Cisco с настроенным рэйд массивом,а в частности с ОС CentOS, я не стал дублировать имя ОС так как оно было написано в названии темы. После Ув. `socode` сказал что данная проблема возникает при обновлении ОС что у меня и произошло, единственное в чем ошибка так это в том что писать в поддержку не CISCO а CentOS. Поэтому я и предложил исправить опечатку. 2-й раз уже с комментарием правки. Спасибо

Comment: @insolor И в комментарии я не упоминал более о компании CISCО, посмотрите пожалуйста внимательнее о чем в комментариях был разговор. Но опечатка исправлена, за что вам спасибо. Всякое бывает.

Comment: @Ethernets, ответ уже отредактирован, вопрос исчерпан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё что я могу вам подсказать это направление. В данном случае откат версии ядра. Но я думаю вы и сами это поняли. Попробуйте написать в поддержку `CentOS`, возможно они вам помогут.